# Data Tables warning Invalid JSON response when refreshing a table using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im currently having a problem refreshing my data table on success function using ajax i dont want to use the window.location.href to refresh the datatable.

Im getting this kind of error and idk why "DataTables warning: table id=datatables - Invalid JSON response" Am I missing something? kinda new in using ajax and datatables.

My AJAX Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    //add quantity
    $(document).on("click", "#btn_add_quantity", function(){
        var getbookisbn = $("#book_isbn").val();
        var getbooktitle = $("#book_title").val();
        var getbookquantity = $("#book_quantity").val();
        var whatprocess = "ADDBOOKQUANTITY";
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "adminfunctions.php",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {
                                getbookisbn:getbookisbn ,
                                getbooktitle:getbooktitle,
                                getbookquantity:getbookquantity,
                                whatprocess: whatprocess
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                var getdata = data.trim();
                                if (getdata == "SUCCESS") {
                                    swal({
                                            title: 'Success!',
                                            text: 'Quantity Added',
                                            type: 'success',
                                            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success",
                                            buttonsStyling: false
                                        }).then(function() {
                    /////REFRESH DATATABLE                        
                                             $('#datatables').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                                    });
                                }else if (getdata == "ERROR") {
                                    swal({
                                            title: 'Sorry...',
                                            text: "You cannot perform that action right now",
                                            type: 'error',
                                            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
                                            buttonsStyling: false
                                        }).then(function() {
                                           fetch_data();
                                    });
                                }
                                else {
                                    swal({
                                        title: 'Sorry for the inconvenience!',
                                        text: "There's a problem. Please contact the technical support for any concerns and questions.!",
                                        type: 'error',
                                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
                                        buttonsStyling: false
                                    }).catch(swal.noop)
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                                console.log(jqXHR);
                            }
                        });
    });
});
```

Script of the datatable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datatables').DataTable({
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "lengthMenu": [
                [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
                [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
            ],
            responsive: true,
            language: {
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
            }

        });
        var table = $('#datatables').DataTable();
        $('.card .material-datatables label').addClass('form-group');
    });
</script>
```

PHP CODE FOR ADDBOOKQUANTITY PROCESS

```
if(isset($_POST["getbookisbn"],$_POST["getbooktitle"],$_POST["getbookquantity"],$_POST["whatprocess"]) && $_POST["whatprocess"] == "ADDBOOKQUANTITY"){

    $getbookisbn = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST["getbookisbn"]));
    $getbooktitle = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST["getbooktitle"]));
    $getbookquantity = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST["getbookquantity"]));
    $resourcename = "Book";
    $action_add = "in";

    // prepare sql query
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_issuance (resource_number, resource_title , resource_name, resource_quantity , in_out) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $getbookisbn, $getbooktitle,$getbookquantity, $resourcename , $action_add);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $addinvent = "UPDATE tbl_bookinventory SET book_quantity = book_quantity + ? WHERE book_isbn = ? ";
        $stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($addinvent);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $getbookquantity, $getbookisbn);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    else{

        echo "ERROR";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the AJAX response, when you try reloading? Check the Network tab and let us know.

Comment: When the datatable warning pops out the it just show the page html code in the network tab

Comment: So that's the problem there. It's sending the whole HTML instead of a JSON. I believe you have to fix that. Else, to confirm, is it possible to make it available in public to test it out?

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: @SmitRaval Ill add the php code responsible for that ADDBOOKQUANTITY process.

Comment: I havent @PraveenKumar upload it on any webhosting :(

Comment: Ah, can you make something like plunker or repl.it?

Comment: Im afraid i cannot i got limited internet connection